# android can not add accessibility on 4.2

Tags: android, accessibility, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have written my own accessibility service. It works fine on 4.1.1 and below. However, I found out that I couldn't find the service on 4.2.2 in Settings>Accessibility. Is there something I should know about accessibily on 4.2.2?

this is I declare in Android Manifest

```
<service android:name="my_service_name"
                    android:label="@string/accessibility_service_lable">
                        <meta-data 
                            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
                    <intent-filter >
                        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </service>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
```

the follow is the config file, it is very simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    />
```

Comment: Can you include the declaration of your service from AndroidManifest.xml, including the contents of the meta-data XML file if you have specified one?

Comment: I added the files, and I also find out that some devices may automatically turn on my accessibility service when the user update my app. Is there any thing configuration for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest should declare the bind permission on your service, rather than as a uses-permission element.

This permission is used to prevent non-system applications from binding to your service, which could potentially be a security issue. If your service doesn't require this permission for binding, then the system will ignore it to protect the user.

So, your manifest should look like:

```
<service android:name="my_service_name"
    android:label="@string/accessibility_service_lable"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great! But I have another problem is that some user  say that the accessibility automatically turn on then they update my app, is there any suggestion about that?